# Replacing string with regex in lxml

Tags: python, regex, lxml

I use Python 2.7, lxml 3.7.3, and [exlst](http://exslt.org/regexp/functions/replace/index.html) extension, for extracting data from XML by using XPath.
I can use regex extension when testing nodes, just like [lxml documentation](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) suggests. Excerpt:

```
>>> regexpNS = "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
>>> find = etree.XPath("//*[re:test(., '^abc$', 'i')]",
...                    namespaces={'re':regexpNS})

>>> root = etree.XML("<root><a>aB</a><b>aBc</b></root>")   
>>> print(find(root)[0].text)
aBc
```

I want to use xpath expression to only produce a substring of the node text().
How do I do that?

Comment: What output do you expect here?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Can you provide an example with the output you're getting now and the output you expect?

Answer (score 0):

To use an xpath expression here, one could do

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring("<root><a>aB</a><b>aBc</b></root>")

for item in root.findall(".//b"):
    print(item.text)
    # aBc
```

See their [**documentation page**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath) for more examples.